# JPA Query mapping

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa

I want to use orderNumber in ProductRepository but I keep getting SQL error. I mapped both sides.

this is product entity.

```
@Entity
public class Product extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "orderItem_id")
    private OrderItem orderItem;
this is orderItem entity.
```

```
@Entity
public class OrderItem extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "orderItem_id")
    private Long id;
    private String orderNumber
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "orderItem", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Builder.Default
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

this is query in ProductRepository.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM OrderItem a, Product b WHERE a.orderItem_id = b.orderItem_id", nativeQuery = true)
    Product findByOrderNumber(String orderNumber);
```

Comment: What error you are getting? Could you add your error as well?

Comment: It occurs Query error. @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM OrderItem a, Product b WHERE a.orderItem_id = b.orderItem_id", nativeQuery = true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can try query by a method as shown below, you don't need to use the `@Query` in this case.

**ProductRepository**

```
 Product findByOrderItemOrderNumber(String orderNumber);
```

you can find more details [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

Comment: Product doesn't have orderNumber tho :(

Comment: It will pick up the `orderNumber ` from `OrderItem`